# Does the Jag's build bonus apply to moving allies' buildings?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-engineer

In Team Fortress 2, the [Engineer weapon the Jag](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Jag) provides a "30% faster construction rate".

When you move a built building it builds at twice the normal speed.  I wonder how far this goes, thus:

Does the Jag's build bonus apply to moving allies' buildings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the wiki page you linked:

> The Jag speeds up the construction of
>   any building as it is being
>   constructed **or redeployed** when the
>   Engineer hits the building with the
>   Jag.

So yes, it applies to moving buildings.

However, as of the last time I played (12/23/2010) you can only move your own buildings, you can't move those belonging to your allies, even with the Jag.

Comment: "However, as of the last time I played (12/23/2010) you can only move your own buildings, you can't move those belonging to your allies, even with the Jag." - Sorry I wasn't clear, I was implying that the ally's building was being redeployed, as in when an ally moves a building.